# SQL regular expression

Tags: mysql, regex

I have 2 columns with names col1 and col2

```
 col1        col2

  abc         abc1 
  pqr         pqr1 
  xyz         axyz1
  bc           dfg
```

I need a third column which has the result of whether col1 is a `substring` in col2

Answer

```
   col1        col2      col3

   abc         abc1      1
   pqr         pqr1      1
   xyz         axyz1     1
   bc          dfg       0
```

Comment: Which sql product are you using? Oracle, mysql, ms sql?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a `case` expression where you check if col2 contains col1 using `like`:

```
select col1, col2, case when col2 like '%' || col1 || '%' then 1 else 0 end
from tablename
```

`||` is ANSI SQL concatenation. Some products have `+` or `concat()` instead.

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server use CASE and CHARINDEX:

```
select col1, col2, 
CASE WHEN CHARINDEX(col1, col2)>0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as col3 
from table
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `sql server`, then you can try as below

```
select [col1], [col2], CASE WHEN CHARINDEX([col1],[col2],1) >0 THEN  1 ELSE 0 END AS Col3
from table1
```

Answer (score 0):

Even shorter (MySQL, at least):

```
SELECT col1, col2, INSTR(col2, col1) > 0
FROM table;
```